# webkit framework iphone

Tags: iphone

i am not able to add webkit framework in my application. Getting error which says no such framework is available.

Comment: Can you give the steps you followed please?

Comment: iOS 4.2 webkit support is not provided. You can tell me what is your requirement. what you want to do using webkit.

Comment: if it's not provided by the system you might be able to add the webkit source to your project and compile it into your binary

Answer (score 4):

The WebKit framework is not available on iPhone - it's only for Macs. The nearest you can get is adding a UIWebView to your app, which gives you a WebKit-based HTML window.

Comment: ya but there are some limitations of uiwebview for which webkit is used. Actually i have to create a web app in iphone, What are the other ways to create one? How to go about it?

Comment: This is no longer accurate as of iOS 8 (WKWebView)