# Can't build/incorporate WebKit framework into iOS project

Tags: ios, xcode, build, webkit, ios-frameworks

I've downloaded the WebCore source code for iOS 4.3.3 from Apple.

Now how do I actually incorporate the WebKit into my iOS project?

I'm not asking how to *use* the WebKit classes. I want to build an iOS app that includes WebKit classes (such as DOM objects), but I don't know how to build the WebKit framework for iOS.

Does any know how to build the WebKit framework for iOS?

Thanks.

Comment: Is it necessary to BUILD the WebKit framework? I select "Add Existing Framework..." and select WebKit from the list of available frameworks.

Comment: However, I am NOT able to BUILD and APP that imports the WebKit framework.

Comment: When I add to my code: `#import <WebKit/WebKit.h>` I get the build error: _WebKit/WebKit.h: No such file or directory.

Comment: possible duplicate of [webkit framework iphone](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4537914/webkit-framework-iphone)

Answer (score 0):

The WebKit framework is not available in iOS. You only have the UIWebView to work with. This question is a good and valid one -- being able to build the WebKit framework yourself for iOs would be very helpful.

Also, this question is a duplicate of [webkit framework iphone](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4537914/webkit-framework-iphone)