# Accessing WebScriptObject with MonoTouch

Tags: c#, ios, uiwebview, webkit, xamarin.ios

I am building a phonegap like solution using MonoTouch & `UIWebView`. I would like to expose a number of C# methods via Javascript. I know you can do this in Objective C using `WebScriptObject` but I can't see where/if this is exposed in the MonoTouch API's.

Is there a way to access `WebScriptObject`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is there a way to access WebScriptObject?

No, [`WebScriptObject`](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/WebKit/Classes/WebScriptObject_Class/Reference/Reference.html) is not part of MonoTouch (like it is part in MonoMac) since `WebKit`, as a framework, [is not part](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6086189/cant-build-incorporate-webkit-framework-into-ios-project) of iOS.

[`UIWebView`](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIWebView_Class/Reference/Reference.html) does allow you to evaluate JavaScript code but I'm not sure (never tried or even looked for) how you can, from there, get back into C# methods.

Answer (score 1):

Just as as corollary to Sebastian's answer you can always create a simple binding that allows your UIWebView to interact with C# code via a HttpListener:

http://yobriefca.se/blog/2011/12/05/rolling-your-own-phonegap-with-monotouch/

You can also use iOS Background threads to interact with other apps via Javascript or C# using HttpListener:

http://blog.devnos.com/remember-when-apps-didnt-talk-to-each-other

Answer (score 1):

As some additional side answers to this...

- you can access javascriptcore - but you will have to work out the bindings for this
- some people have managed to use Jint (0.9 or older - with no Reflection.Emit JIT code)